# ошибка fetch API

Tags: javascript, api, fetch

строка запроса к API в Postman работает
та же самая строка в fetch на JS - запрос возвращает ошибку
что может быть ? (Failed to fetch )

Comment: Секретную ошибку?

Comment: Failed to fetch

Answer (score 1):

Осмелюсь предположить что это [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

> В целях безопасности браузеры ограничивают cross-origin запросы,
> инициируемые скриптами. Например, XMLHttpRequest и Fetch API следуют
> политике одного источника (same-origin policy). Это значит, что
> web-приложения, использующие такие API, могут запрашивать HTTP-ресурсы
> только с того домена, с которого были загружены, пока не будут
> использованы CORS-заголовки.

Comment: а как ее победить?) ведь fetch делается с фронта

Comment: через свой сервер

Comment: так в том то и дело что нет сервера) SPA безсерверный делает fetch)

Comment: кто поднимает SPA? если не сервер

Comment: сервера нет  - есть фронт .SPA - просто выложенно на хостинг

Comment: Так вот хостинг сервер и есть сервер. Добавьте туда кода который будет запрашивать данные из другого источника и передавать на фронт. По сути посадить на сервер постман который будут общяться и внешним источником и отдавать на фронт данные

Comment: хостинг сторонний - он не позволяет размещать там сервера

Comment: тогда просите сторонний источник что раздрешил CORS для вашего сайта